# Track Delivery Status of Messages in Python

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I keep getting caught up tracking delivery status of messages in Flask, Twilio, and Python.  I found the below code on Twilio's docs for tracking delivery but am having a hard time implementing it.

How would I go from the below code to actually seeing the delivery status of a message within Python?  I have ngrok running but am confused where to put that url.  Any help is appreciated!

```
from flask import Flask, request
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/MessageStatus", methods=['POST'])
def incoming_sms():
    message_sid = request.values.get('MessageSid', None)
    message_status = request.values.get('MessageStatus', None)
    logging.info('SID: {}, Status: {}'.format(message_sid, message_status))

    return ('', 204)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You provide the URL as `status_callback` when you [send the SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-python?code-sample=code-send-an-sms-with-a-statuscallback-url&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x):

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
# DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages \
    .create(
         body='McAvoy or Stewart? These timelines can get so confusing.',
         from_='+15017122661',
         status_callback='http://postb.in/1234abcd',
         to='+15558675310'
     )

print(message.sid)
```

So instead of the `postb.in` URL above, change that to your ngrok URL.  However be aware that the ngrok URL changes every time you restart the connector, unless on the paid plan [(apparently)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050182/how-to-generate-fixed-url-with-ngrok).   So you'd need to change the URL in the above code, every time you restart the ngrok connector.

With that in mind, you can then set up the separate app to [handle the callback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-python?code-sample=code-handle-a-sms-statuscallback&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x) as per the code block in your question.

---

**UPDATE**

> I'm able to do the call out but I am still having issues with Flask and the call back status.

I don't have an account with Twillio to test, but I'd first check that the callback request is actually hitting your Flask server.

I would assume from the doc's code samples, that with `status_callback` URL of `http://postb.in/1234abcd` that request actually hits the endpoint `http://postb.in/1234abcd/MessageStatus`, however it's possible that's a mistake and the flask code should be: `@app.route('/1234abcd')` if you provided such a URL. (This isn't too clear in the docs).

If you're certain the request is reaching the server, but your code isn't handling it properly, it may be wise to set up a [catch-all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13678543/2052575) route like:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''}, methods=['POST'])
@app.route('/<path:path>', methods=['POST'])
def catch_all(path):
    print (path, request.url, request.get_data())
    return ('', 204)
```

This will allow you to inspect any requests reaching the server, regardless of the path.

You could also test this catch-all route with the `requests` library (not to be confused with Flask's `request` object by the way!):

```
# From any other terminal
import requests
r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/',json={1:2})
r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/asd',data={3:4})
```

Server console output:

```
http://localhost:5000/ b'{"1": 2}'
172.17.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2020 23:11:55] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
asd http://localhost:5000/asd b'3=4'
172.17.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2020 23:12:00] "POST /asd HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to do the call out but I am still having issues with Flask and the call back status.  How would you do that?