# Configuring a Flask application running on gunicorn to run behind a file path

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to configure a Flask application hosted with gunicorn to run behind a file path.
The current app is designed to run at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), but I would like to configure it to run at example.com/foo/bar

The difficulty I am having is that I can't seem to get the requests to be sent to the application. It currently works fine if you go to example.com, but going to example.com/foo/bar results in nothing. Everything is done through AWS. The networking has been setup to pass example.com/foo/bar requests to the server. The Flask init is as follows:

```
import os
from functools import wraps

import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response, redirect, Response, g

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['VERSION'] = '3.7.2'
app.config['SERVER_ADDRESS'] = os.environ.get('SERVER_ADDRESS', 'https://example.com/')
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/foo/bar/'

@app.before_request
def set_server_address():
    g.server_address = app.config['SERVER_ADDRESS']

@app.route('/')
def index(*args, **kwargs):
    return redirect('/app/example')
```

When I check the logs after visiting example.com/foo/bar, there is no traffic. Any light which could be shed on this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by adding the /foo/bar to your flask route.

```py
@app.route('/foo/bar')
def make_homepage():
    return 'success'
```

But it's not best practice because each time the response will be as a redirect and with high traffic it's could be pretty resource intensive, so i will recommend to you to check this question:
[Python - Flask Default Route possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678397/python-flask-default-route-possible)